# Left ideals of $\ell^{\infty}(A)$ containing all weakly null sequences in a Banach algebra $A$

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a Banach algebra. $\ell^{\infty}(A)$, the space of all bounded sequences in $A$, is a Banach algebra with pointwise operations.

Let $w_0(A)$ be the subspace of all weakly null sequences in $A$.

**Question 1:** What is the smallest left (resp. right) ideal that contains $w_0(A)$? What are the necessary conditions for this ideal to be a maximal modular left (resp. right) ideal? Can it be equal to $\ell^{\infty}(A)$?

**Question 2:** Same question when $A$ is a reflexive unital Banach algebra.

---

For example; $w_0(A)$ is a *two-sided ideal* when $A=\ell^p$ for $1<p<\infty$, $A=c_0$, $A=C(K)$ for a compact Hausdorff space $K$, $A=L^p(G)$ for $1<p<\infty$ and a compact group $G$, $A=\ell^1$ with convolution, $A=J$ the James space with the pointwise multiplication.

$w_0(A)$ is a closed *subalgebra* but not an ideal when $A=L^1(\mathbb{R})$ with convolution.

---

Edit (23.12.2021): I am not aware of a description of the maximal modular left ideals (or primitive ideals) of $\ell^{\infty}(A)$ that contain $w_0(A)$. It would be great if you direct me to a reference.

Comment: The injective tensor product of $\ell_\infty$ and $A$ consists of the sequences in $A$ having a relatively compact range; so it's not (canonically) isomorphic to $\ell_\infty(A)$.

Comment: Certainly $\ell^\infty \hat{\otimes}_\epsilon \ell^\infty$ is not isometric to $\ell^\infty$, by the Banach-Stone theorem (because $\beta\mathbb{N} \times \beta\mathbb{N}$ is not homeomorphic to $\beta\mathbb{N}$). I don't know if this can be upgraded to nonexistence of any isomorphism of Banach spaces.

Comment: @RobertFurber I vaguely recall some results of Tomek Kania in this vein which show that certain Grothendieck spaces, including von Neumann algebras but also some "large" Cstar algebras, can't be factorized as injective tensor products of infinite-dimensional spaces - but perhaps Tomek's result goes through the special case you are asking about

Comment: @DirkWerner $\ell^{\infty}\hat{\otimes}_{\epsilon}A = C(\beta\mathbb{N})\hat{\otimes}_{\epsilon}A = C(\beta\mathbb{N},A)$. After a quick thought, I concluded $C(\beta\mathbb{N},A)$ and $\ell^{\infty}(A)$ are isomorphic. I edit the post to fix my mistake. Thank you for your correction.

Comment: @RobertFurber Thank you for your comment. Surely $\ell^{\infty}$ is a Grothendieck space while $\ell^{\infty}\hat{\otimes}_{\epsilon}\ell^{\infty} = C(\beta\mathbb{N}\times \beta\mathbb{N})$ is not. https://doi.org/10.1093/qmath/hav027 must be the article that Yemon Choi has pointed at.

Comment: Yes to both. The example https://mathoverflow.net/a/395832 is Hilbertian and has a weakly null "unitary" sequence.

Comment: Professor @NarutakaOZAWA , it is true that the smallest subalgebra that contains $w_0(A)$ is $\ell^{\infty}(A)$ for the algebra you had graciously provided. In fact, having two weakly null sequences $(x_n)$, $(y_n)$ for which $x_ny_n\to 1$ weakly, is a sufficient condition for this. It would be great to see necessary conditions that make $\ell^{\infty}(A)w_0(A)$ a maximal modular left ideal for a general Banach algebra $A$. Respectfully..

Comment: I am not aware of a description of the maximal modular left ideals of $\ell^{\infty}(A)$ that contain $w_0(A)$, for a general Banach algebra $A$. It would be great if you could direct me to a reference.

Comment: $\ell_\infty(A)$ has the ultrapower $A^U$, $U\in\beta\mathbb{N}$, as a quotient. It's a difficult problem to decide whether $A^U$ is simple. In any case, this tells that the closed ideal generated by $w_0(A)$ is either non-maximal or $\ell_\infty(A)$.